# Problem with c# code: error CS0176: Member 'Camera.main' cannot be accessed with an instance reference

Tags: c#, instance

I was trying to copy a code from youtube for changing a scene camera and other objects but i've got this error:  error CS0176: Member 'Camera.main' cannot be accessed with an instance reference; qualify it with a type name instead;

This is the code:

'''using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class PlayerSetup : NetworkBehaviour
{

```
[SerializeField]
Behaviour[] componentsToDisable;

public Camera sceneCamera;

void Start()
{
    if (!isLocalPlayer)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < componentsToDisable.Length; i++)
        {
            componentsToDisable[i].enabled = false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        sceneCamera = sceneCamera.main;
        if (sceneCamera!= null) 
        {
            Camera.main.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }

    }
}

void OnDisable ()
{

    if (sceneCamera != null)
    {
        sceneCamera.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }
}
```

}'''

I'm not in a hurry but if you can help me thank you.

Comment: Presumably `sceneCamera = sceneCamera.main;` should be `sceneCamera = Camera.main;`, just like you do 3 lines later

Comment: Thanks very much, I'm new with coding and c# and excuse me for this stupid error :-)